# Circular Loader with Percentage and Texts in React and Material-UI

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I have here a `CircularLoader` using Material UI.
My only problem is that if the variant is `indeterminate` then show the loader as is with no percentage while if it is `determinate` show the percentage inside the loader and the text as is.

Codesandbox: [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/circularwithvaluelabel-material-demo-forked-smsow?file=/demo.js)

```
const CircularLoader = (props) => {
  const {
    height = "auto",
    color = "primary",
    text = "",
    value = 0,
    variant = "indeterminate"
  } = props;

  return (
    <Grid
      component="div"
      container
      justifyContent="center"
      alignItems="center"
      flexDirection="column"
      sx={{ height }}
    >
      <CircularProgress
        // variant={variant}
        // value={value}
        disableShrink
        color={color}
        thickness={4}
        sx={{ marginBottom: "0.5rem" }}
      />
      <Typography variant="body1" component="div" color={color}>
        {text}
      </Typography>
    </Grid>
  );
};
export default CircularLoader;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's probably best to split these components up (since they have different props). But if you want them in the same component, you need to provide a **dynamic** value from 0-100 to the `determinate` variant. See the docs [source code example](https://mui.com/components/progress/#CircularDeterminate.js).

In your case you could have a ternary choose between which variant to render, as a quick demo the following should work (note i'm ignoring value prop and simulating it with `progress` for demo purposes):

```
import React from "react";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import CircularProgress from "@mui/material/CircularProgress";
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

const CircularLoader = ({
  height = "auto",
  color = "primary",
  text = "",
  value = 0,
  variant = "indeterminate"
}) => {
  const [progress, setProgress] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setProgress((prevProgress) =>
        prevProgress >= 100 ? 0 : prevProgress + 10
      );
    }, 800);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <Grid
      component="div"
      container
      justifyContent="center"
      alignItems="center"
      flexDirection="column"
      sx={{ height }}
    >
      {variant === "indeterminate" ? (
        <CircularProgress />
      ) : (
      <Stack spacing={2} direction="row">
       <Box sx={{ position: 'relative', display: 'inline-flex' }}>
        <CircularProgress variant="determinate" value={progress}/>
        <Box
        sx={{
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          right: 0,
          position: 'absolute',
          display: 'flex',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}
      >
        <Typography variant="caption" component="div" color="text.secondary">
          {`${Math.round(progress)}%`}
        </Typography>
      </Box>
    </Box>
        </Stack>
      )}

      <Typography variant="body1" component="div" color={color}>
        {text}
      </Typography>
    </Grid>
  );
};
export default CircularLoader;
```

`progress` is just simulated in this case for demo purposes, whereas you need to pass down progress as `value` via props and use that in the CircularProgress component (it should be some dynamic value linked to actual loading progress state).

[Link to Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/circularwithvaluelabel-material-demo-forked-23tub?file=/components/CircularLoader.js)

Comment: Can you fork the codesandbox?

Comment: Added link to forked sandbox

Comment: I can't see the percentage inside the circular loader?

Comment: Added, you need to control that separately, see updated sandbox, also link to docs - https://mui.com/components/progress/#CircularWithValueLabel.js

Comment: Thank you. How do you add some space between the percentage and the loader? Its quite fit. I have added thickness by the way. https://codesandbox.io/s/circularwithvaluelabel-material-demo-forked-gxhlx?file=/components/CircularLoader.js

Comment: You can give the Circular loader a size prop (see sandbox). Please accept my answer as I have already answered your main question.